Linear Analysis Bollobas Exercise 3.11 - Properties of Intersections of Dense Subspaces
There are 4 parts to this question, and I've been able to figure out 2 of them.

Let $X_1, X_2$ be arbitrary dense subspaces. Then their intersection need not be dense. Example: Let $X = L_2(0,1)$. Then both the space of polynomials and $\operatorname{lin}(\sin(nx))$ are dense sets whose intersection is trivial.
Let $X_1$ be a 1-codimensional dense subspace of $X$. Then $X_1\cap Y$ is dense in $Y.$ Since they are 1-codimensional subspaces, there exists an unbounded linear functional $f_1$ such that $\ker f_1 = X_1$ and an a bounded linear functional $f_0$ such that $\ker f_0 = Y$. $f:= f_1 + f_0$ is thus an unbounded linear operator. Further, $f$ must be unbounded on $Y$ as well. If it were bounded on $Y$, then since $Y$ is 1-codimensional, we have, for a fixed $z \notin Y$, that $\forall x \in X$, $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb F, y \in Y$ such that $x = y + \alpha z$. Thus, $f(y + \alpha z) = f_0(y) + \alpha f_0(z)$, which is thus a bounded functional. Since $f$ is unbounded on $Y$, then $\ker f$ is dense in $Y,$ and $\ker f = X_1 \cap Y$.

I have not been able to make progress on the other two questions. My intuition is that if $X_1$ is not 1-codimensional, then $X_1 \cap Y$ need not be dense in $Y$. I tried approaching this by constructing a linear functional whose kernel contains a non-dense subset of $\mathbb Q[x]$ (ala Timothy Gowers), but I have had no luck.
In addition, I'm also stuck on the other question, is $X_1 \cap X_2$ dense when these are 1-codimensional subspaces. I tried using the same approach as I did in 2., but the sum of two discontinuous functionals need not be discontinuous (although I suppose this does present some sort of counter example).


Recall that for a non-zero linear functional $f$ on a vector space $V$, the kernel of $f$ is a vector subspace of codimension $1$ in $V$. Furthermore, if $V$ is a normed space (or a Hausdorff topological vector space), $f$ is continuous if and only if $\ker (f)$ is closed in $V$, which occurs (because $\ker (f)$ has codimension $1$ in $V$) if and only if $\ker (f)$ is not dense in $V$. As a consequence, $f$ is discontinuous if and only if $\ker (f)$ is dense in $V$.
Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Let $f$ be a non-zero continuous linear functional on $X$ and let $g$ be a discontinuous linear functional on $X$. Then $f+g$ is a discontinuous linear functional on $X$. Furthermore, $\ker (f+g)$ and $\ker (g)$ are dense $1$-codimensional subspaces of $X$ and $\ker (f)$ is a closed $1$-codimensional subspace of $X$. Because $f = (f+g)-g$, $\ker (f+g) \cap \ker (g) = \ker (f) \cap \ker (g)$. Also since $f\neq g$, $\ker (f) \cap \ker (g)$ is a $2$-codimensional subspace of $X$.
Define $X_{1} := \ker (f+g)$, $X_{2} := \ker (g)$ and $Y := \ker (g)$. Then $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$ and $Y$ are $1$-codimensional dense subspaces of $X$. Since $X_{1}\cap X_{2} = \ker (f)\cap \ker (g)$ and $\ker (f)$ is a proper closed subspace of $X$ containing $\ker (f) \cap \ker (g)$, $X_{1}\cap X_{2}$ is not dense in $X$. Furthermore, $X_{1}\cap Y$ cannot be closed in $X$ because finite-dimensional extensions of closed subspaces are again closed subspaces and $X_{1}$ is a $1$-dimensional extension of $X_{1}\cap Y$. Then as the $1$-dimensional extension $\ker (f)$ of $X_{1}\cap Y$ is closed in $X$, $\overline{X_{1}\cap Y}^{X} = \ker (f)$. It follows that
$$\overline{X_{1}\cap Y}^{Y} = \overline{X_{1}\cap Y}^{X} \cap Y = \ker (f) \cap \ker (g) = X_{1}\cap Y.$$
Hence $X_{1}\cap Y$ is closed in $Y$. But as $X_{1}\cap Y$ has codimension $2$ in $X$ while $Y$ has codimension $1$ in $X$, $X_{1}\cap Y$ is a proper subspace of $Y$ and $X_{1}\cap Y$ is not dense in $Y$.
This disproves all of the statements in the question.
